# AutoPopulate attribute not working on AutoQuery DTO

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to get the new AutoPopulate attribute to work but I am having some difficulty understanding the new AutoQuery functionality.

To test it out I am aiming to replace this service that is a standard AutoQuery endpoint but it also filters by the logged in users ID.  I want to replace it so it works completely with just the model definition.

```cs
public class DevExtremeService : ServiceBase
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public QueryResponse<DeWatchedUrlResponse> Any(WatchedUrlDevExRequest request)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateDevXQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams(), Request);

        q.Where(x => x.UserAuthCustomId == GetUserId());

        var response = AutoQuery.Execute(request, q, base.Request);

        return response;
    }


}

[Route("/de/watched-urls")]
public class WatchedUrlDevExRequest : QueryDb<WatchedUrlRecord, DeWatchedUrlResponse>
{

}
```

So I deleted the service and updated model to:

```cs
[ValidateIsAuthenticated]
[AutoPopulate(nameof(WatchedUrlDevExRequest.UserAuthCustomId), Eval = "userAuthId")]
[Route("/de/watched-urls")]
public class WatchedUrlDevExRequest : QueryDb<WatchedUrlRecord, DeWatchedUrlResponse>
{
    public long UserAuthCustomId { get; set; }
}
```

My understanding from reading the release notes is that `userAuthId` is a variable declared in the AutoQuery #script context that is added by default.

I have tried a few different variations and I cannot get the property to populate.  The docs seem focused on audit history and multitenancy but really I am just looking for a quick way to make endpoints.

I have 2 main questions:

1. Why is the auto populate not working on this property?
2. Where can I see the default #script definition so I can see how things like `userAuthId` are defined and better get an understanding how to add my own?

*edit*

I re-read docs and I gues this only works when writing data to db.  I really like the concept of being able to apply #script to a request model via attribute.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoQuery CRUD's [[AutoPopulate]](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud#autopopulate) attribute initially only populated AutoQuery CRUD's Data Model when performing CRUD operations, e.g. Inserting, Updating or Deleting entities.

For ensuring a query only returns a users records, it's recommended to [use an AutoFilter](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud#autofilter) instead, which behaves as expected ensuring the query is always applied to the Data Model, e.g:

```
[ValidateIsAuthenticated]
[Route("/de/watched-urls")]
[AutoFilter(QueryTerm.Ensure, nameof(WatchedUrlRecord.UserAuthCustomId),  
            Eval = "userAuthId")]
public class WatchedUrlDevExRequest : QueryDb<WatchedUrlRecord, DeWatchedUrlResponse>
{
}
```

However as I can see it's a useful feature I've also just added support for `[AutoPopulate]` & `[AutoMap]` attributes on Query DTOs in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b71037b42078af9bed5e8ad9db951a56ccfdb0e3) where your AutoQuery DTO would work as expected where it populates the Request DTO property:

```
[ValidateIsAuthenticated]
[AutoPopulate(nameof(WatchedUrlDevExRequest.UserAuthCustomId), Eval = "userAuthId")]
[Route("/de/watched-urls")]
public class WatchedUrlDevExRequest : QueryDb<WatchedUrlRecord, DeWatchedUrlResponse>
{
    public long UserAuthCustomId { get; set; }
}
```

This change is available from v5.10.3 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

An alternative approach to populate AutoQuery's Request DTO you could have a custom AutoQuery implementation like you have, an Extensible [Query Filter or custom base class](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#extensibility-with-queryfilters) or I'd personally go with a [Global Request Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) that updates all Request DTOs with a shared interface, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    if (dto is IHasUserAuthCustomId authDto)
    {
        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (session.IsAuthenticated)
            authDto.UserAuthCustomId = session.UserAuthId;
    }
});
```

Or you could wrap this logic in a [Request Filter Attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) and apply the behavior to Request DTOs that way.

Note: `userAuthId` is a [ServiceStack #Script method](https://sharpscript.net/docs/servicestack-scripts) that returns the currently authenticated User Id.

Comment: Thanks mythz for the helpful and quick response.  I hadn't noticed the custom filter attributes before, that looks ideal for what I am trying to do.  Would you mind telling me where the #script default methods like `userAuthId` are defined?  I would like to see a bit more how they work to get some understanding

Comment: @Guerrilla I linked to the [ServiceStack #Script Methods](https://sharpscript.net/docs/servicestack-scripts#info-scripts) page, also the [Scripts API Reference](https://sharpscript.net/docs/scripts-reference) lets you explore built-in #Script methods.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood.  I thought that it was defined in the autoquery plugin, didn't realise it was built into #script itself.  I will have a look, thanks

Comment: @Guerrilla FYI please see updated answer as using `[AutoFilter(QueryTerm.Ensure,..)]` is the recommended way to filter by authenticated user. I've also just added support for `[AutoPopulate]` and `[AutoMap]` on Query Request DTOs.

Comment: That's great!  Many thanks for adding this, it will be something that I use

Comment: I tried with `[AutoFilter(QueryTerm.Ensure, nameof(WatchedUrlRecord.UserAuthCustomId), Eval = "userAuthId")]` but I think there is an issue because my user IDs are type `long` and I think this is returning a string as I get error `42883: operator does not exist: bigint = text`.  (I am using postgresql)

Comment: I tried `{{userAuthId  |>  long}}` but no joy.  What is right way to handle type conversion in #script?

Comment: @Guerrilla you can view & search the [Script API Reference](https://sharpscript.net/docs/scripts-reference?nameContains=long&tab=default-scripts) to find out built-in API methods, e.g. `toLong` coerces to a long value. It's also easy to [register your own Script Methods](https://sharpscript.net/docs/methods). Note the `Eval` expressions uses [#Script code](https://sharpscript.net/scode/), i.e. no `{{...}}` template literals.